Ratio of first moment square and second moment of the largest eigen value of a wishart matrix.
Can anyone help prove that:
$$\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=n-m}^{(n+m)k-2k^{2}}d^{'}_{k,l} \frac{(l+1)} { (k)^{1}}\right)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=n-m}^{(n+m)k-2k^{2}}d^{'}_{k,l} \frac{(l+1)(l+2)} { (k)^{2}}}=1$$
Where $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=n-m}^{(n+m)k-2k^{2}}d^{'}_{k,l} =1$$
and $n \geq m$
